# GCloud IAM Restore

Tags: gcloud

I was with the "Owner" role and accidentally I changed it to the "Editor" role. Now, I can't find how to change it back to "Owner" role. I am seeing the below error.

> You need permissions for this action. Required permission(s):
> resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're reduced your superpowers from Owner to Editor and, as an Editor, you're not permitted to grant yourself the more powerful, Owner role.

You'll need to either find another project Owner or organizational Admin to bump you back to Owner **or** contact Google Cloud Support for help.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I was the owner and I have added some of my teammates as Editor. None of them could make revert me back, because no one has right to change the IAM stuff. I think, this is something @Gcloud team must think that at lease 1 owner must present and it can't be removed. This is the basic I guess and the rule is missing.

Comment: That's not an unreasonable requirement. Before Organizations were added, Projects were the 'root' (security) object in GCP. With Organizations, there's now a higher-level of admin but their role in each Project can be implicit (inherited). I suspect this complicates determining how many Owners there are **but** your point is a good one. Perhaps submit it using Google's Issue Tracker for [Cloud IAM](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187161&template=1162660)? Cloud Support should be able to resolve this issue for you.